# Serializing Enum type emits different element name

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

Working on XML serialization. When serializing enum type, xml element name of it to be changed. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using .Net xml serialization to serialize this object and that produces the below xml output

```
<MyEnums>   <MyEnum>One</MyEnum>    <MyEnum>Two</MyEnum>    <MyEnum>Three</MyEnum></MyEnums>
```

Here is the class

```
public class Request
{
        public List<MyEnum> MyEnums { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the XML I wanted to emit

```
<MyEnums>
<ModifiedElementName>One</ModifiedElementName>
<ModifiedElementName>Two</ModifiedElementName>
<ModifiedElementName>Three</ModifiedElementName>
```

Here is Enum Type

```
enum MyEnum
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

Expecting output be as xml

```
<ModifiedElementName>One</ModifiedElementName>
```

Comment: Can you please show what you are trying and why it is not working as you expect? It is hard to see what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Can you also show sample class (or classes) - it is not exactly clear if you want to make the change for one particular class or all classes using the Enum.

Comment: why don't you make the first value in the enum =1 and the rest will come in `ordinal` sequence? also, how are you Serializing the enum ? do you have that code or are you expecting someone to write that for you..?

Comment: Updated the question, if more information required, please let me know

Comment: And right now, you're getting `<MyEnums><MyEnum>One</MyEnum></MyEnums>` instead of `<MyEnums><ModifiedElementName>One</ModifiedElementName></MyEnums>`?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am using xml serialization in .Net.I have code written already. Not sure which XML attribute change the name of the element. I tried XMLElement attribute on Enum type but code does not compile as XML element does not apply to Type instead properties.

Comment: @hvd Correct That is output I am getting now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `XmlType` attribute on your `enum`, like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Scratch
{
    [XmlType("ModifiedEnumName")]
    public enum TestEnum
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three,
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
            MyEnums = new List<TestEnum>();
        }

        public List<TestEnum> MyEnums { get; set; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass)).Serialize(sw, new TestClass { MyEnums = { TestEnum.Two } });
                Console.WriteLine(sw.GetStringBuilder());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TestClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MyEnums>
    <ModifiedEnumName>Two</ModifiedEnumName>
  </MyEnums>
</TestClass>
```

Edit: this assumes all `TestEnum`s need to be serialised the same way. If you wish to be able to specify different XML element names for different properties of the same type, go with carlosfigueira's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the `[XmlElement]`, `[XmlArray]` and `[XmlArrayItem]` attributes to get what you want. The example below uses the last two to get to what I think you need, but feel free to play with the others to get exactly the XML you want output.

```
    public class Request
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "MyEnums")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "ModifiedElementName")]
        public List<MyEnum> MyEnums { get; set; }
    }

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Request req = new Request
        { 
            MyEnums = new List<MyEnum>
            {
                MyEnum.One,
                MyEnum.Two,
                MyEnum.Three
            }
        };
        xs.Serialize(ms, req);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    }
```

Comment: Ah, your answer shows how to modify this per property, rather than per type (as in my answer). Which is better depends on the situation, it could well be that that's your answer.